# Array Problems Math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrays

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{llll} \hline
& \multirow{2}{*}{\tilde{b}\leq b^{NG}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tilde{b}>b^{NG}} \\ \cline{3-4}
& & b^{G} \leq \tilde{b} & b^{G}>\tilde{b} \\ \hline
b^{UL} & b^{NG} & \tilde{b} & b^{G} \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

This is the error I get:

**Package amsmath Error: \tilde allowed only in math mode.ng text**

It  tried at changing \tilde{b} to $\tilde{b}$ but it gave the same error.
I do not understand why this is not working as I created a math environment for the array by using \[ and \].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The argument to `\multirow` is typeset in text mode. It's only `\multicolumn` that adjusts to math mode in `array` and text mode in `tabular`.

Comment: thanks a lot egreg for the fast answer. that is the fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `\multirow` is always typeset in text mode, unlike the argument of `\multicolumn` that knows to distinguish between being called by `array` or `tabular`.

I suggest using the rules of `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{llll}
\toprule[\lightrulewidth]
& \multirow{2}{*}{$\tilde{b}\leq b^{NG}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tilde{b}>b^{NG}} \\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{3-4}
& & b^{G} \leq \tilde{b} & b^{G}>\tilde{b} \\
\midrule
b^{UL} & b^{NG} & \tilde{b} & b^{G} \\
\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, avoiding `multirow` is even better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{llll}
\toprule[\lightrulewidth]
& \tilde{b}\leq b^{NG} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tilde{b}>b^{NG}} \\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{3-4}
& & b^{G} \leq \tilde{b} & b^{G}>\tilde{b} \\
\midrule
b^{UL} & b^{NG} & \tilde{b} & b^{G} \\
\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx egreg. this looks even better in spacing and you can manually set the thickness of the horizontal lines! Awesome!